# Executing ssh command with args using Golang os/exec leads to Exit status 127

Tags: go, ssh, exec

In my golang program, I need to execute a command on a remote server via ssh.
My computer has a private key stored to connect to the server without password.

Here's my code for running remote commands:

```golang
out, err := exec.Command("ssh", "myserver.com", "'ls'").Output()
fmt.Println(string(out), err)
```

This code works as expected, however, when I add arguments to the command executed on the ssh server, the I get an error with `Exit Status 127`

Example Code:

```golang
out, err := exec.Command("ssh", "myserver.com", "'ls .'").Output()
fmt.Println(string(out), err, exercise)
```

This code leads to: `exit status 127`

How do I have to format my ssh command in order to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is another argument in your command which has to be passed in the argument list separately:

```
out, err := exec.Command("ssh", "myserver.com", "ls", ".").Output()
```

or:

```
out, err := exec.Command("ssh", "myserver.com", "ls", "/path/to/any/other/dir").Output()
```

Comment: Omg, I didn't know that the ssh command can also be passed without `''`. This works indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding ssh you also might have a look into: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh
For better security and advanced control

Comment: @Tobi696 Don't forget to accpet this answer.